# Cabin baggage allowance in Jet airways

Tags: indian-citizens, hand-luggage, domestic-travel, jet-airways

I will be travelling from Munich to Mumbai (economy class) and from Mumbai I have a separate domestic flight to Bangalore through Jet Airways (economy class).

The Lufthansa flight allows for 2 cabin baggage. Does Jet Airways also have the same policy with cabin baggage for domestic flights ? If not what is the workaround ?

Comment: Since your flight seems to be on two separate tickets, there is no workaround. If you exceed the limits for either carrier you have to face the consequences. Are you flying business class on Lufthansa? If not then your limitation there is more likely to be one carry-on plus one "personal item."  Regardless, we can't answer without knowing your class of service. Please edit the question to include it.

Comment: @phoog my baggage are within the limits for the lufthansa flight but my question lies with the allowance for the jet airways flight. am i allowed an additional laptop bag along with the 7 kilo trolley ? I dont mind paying extra for the additional cabin bag. I just want to know if they will allow me to board the flight with 2 pieces of luggage(1 trolley and 1 laptop bag)

Comment: The answer can be found in seconds on the Jet Airways website. If you want to know something simple like this about an airline, it's almost always faster to just look at their website than to post a question on the internet and wait for somebody to respond.

Comment: Yes, the Jet Airways website - http://www.jetairways.com/EN/NL/TravelInformation/Baggage/cabin-baggage.aspx states that you can bring only one bag into the cabin. But I have travelled the Frankfurt India route many times. And it included taking domestic flights within India as a separate ticket. I have always carried a laptop bag as well as a small cabin sized trolley bag with me on board the aircraft and never have been stopped. 
However, my answer is very specific to Chennai, Kochi, Coimbatore airports in the south of India. But you should not have a problem at Bangalore airport as well.

Comment: @Müller the site also lists "a laptop" among the additional items allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Jet Airways website](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/TravelInformation/Baggage/cabin-baggage.aspx) clearly states that you can only bring one bag into the cabin, and claims that this restriction is due to the Indian government.

Comment: On the other hand, if you scroll down a bit, there's a list of additional items allowed in the cabin, which includes "a laptop."

Comment: @phoog But not a laptop bag. On the other hand, it doesn't say you have to be a lady to bring "a lady's handbag".

Comment: I suspect that listing "a laptop" without mentioning the case in which it is carried is an oversight on the part of the person or people preparing the list. I also suspect that a man showing up with a lady's handbag would be permitted to take it. The most glaring oversight, however, is probably the failure to mention a limit on the number of additional items permitted.